# Under what circumstances does SiteLogoUrl work?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

Of all the times I've set the SiteLogoUrl attribute of the [Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms438080.aspx) element in the onet.xml file, I think it has only worked once without my giving up and setting SiteLogoUrl in a Feature Receiver. What's the secret? AlternateCSS works as expected, why not SiteLogoUrl?

Answer (score 1):

According tho [this official answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010general/thread/b16fe0fd-1981-4a89-99b1-9818cc544860), it seems to be a bug that will hopefully be fixed in an upcoming CU / Service Pack.

Comment: Thanks. It was SP 2007 that I was having trouble with (and have retagged the question to reflect that). But that's very interesting about SP 2010.

Comment: It still does not work in SP 2010. What's crazy is that SiteLogoDescription works, but SiteLogoUrl does not !