# Custom template/onet.xml and icon link in SharePoint2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

How can I change the link URL for the icon in the [picture](http://img233.imageshack.us/img233/5774/siteicon.png)

I have a custom template and when I create a new site from it I want the link to take the user to the main portal site. I have about 10 site collections with a copy of the template each. I think I can go to the main site in each site collection and set all subsites to inherit from the 'this' site but I don't want to do this every time I create a new site.

In onet.xml I set the url to the custom icon:

```
<Project Title="test" Revision="0" UIVersion="4" SiteLogoUrl="/SiteCollectionImages/test.png" SiteLogoDescription="" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
```

Can I also set the link URL?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SiteLogoUrl does not work in the onet.xml file. You need to set it programmatically using [SPWeb.SiteLogoUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.sitelogourl.aspx).

See also: [Under what circumstances does SiteLogoUrl work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382077/under-what-circumstances-does-sitelogourl-work)

Comment: I'm sorry if I was unclear but what I meant is the URL the user is taken to when they click on the icon, not the URL to icon itself.

Comment: Ah. To set that, you have to modify the master page. Look for an SPLinkButton with an id of onetidProjectPropertyTitleGraphic. By default, NavigateUrl="~site/". You can change NavigateUrl to a URL of your choosing.